# Receiving dojo.io.script error Error: Invalid URL?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I am trying to get a buffer circle on my map,when I click on map. I tried with the following code, but I got error:

> dojo.io.script error Error: Invalid URL

How can I avoid this error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

    </style>
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;

      require([ "esri/map",
                "dojo/on",
                "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
                "esri/layers/ImageParameters",
                "esri/tasks/Geoprocessor",
                "esri/tasks/FeatureSet",
                "dojo/dom",                
                "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map,on,ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,ImageParameters,Geoprocessor,FeatureSet,dom) {
          map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "streets",  
          center: [72, 25.75], 
          zoom: 5
        });

        var imageParameters = new ImageParameters();
        imageParameters.format = "PNG24";

         var gp = new Geoprocessor("http://iicss63:6080/arcgis/rest/services/NCAOR/XYZtoR/GPServer");

         map.on("click", createBuffer);
         function createBuffer(){
        var params = {"InputFile":FeatureSet,
                      "BUFFER_30_shp":FeatureSet}
        gp.submitJob(params, completeCallback, statusCallback);

        };

        function completeCallback(jobInfo) {
        console.log("getting data");
        gp.getResultData(jobInfo.jobId, displayResult);
      } 
            function displayResult(result, messages) {
           var simpleLineSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
              new dojo.Color([255,255,0]), 1);
           var features = result.value.features;
              for (var f=0, fl=features.length; f<fl; f++) {
          var feature = features[f];
          feature.setSymbol(simpleLineSymbol);
          map.graphics.add(feature);
      }
    }
        function statusCallback(jobInfo) {
      console.log(jobInfo.jobStatus);
    }


     });



    </script>
  </head>

  <body> 
    <div id="map">  
        <span id="xyco" style="position:absolute; left:15px; bottom:5px; color:#000; z-index:50;"></span>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that the url in the following line of code is not available:

```
var gp = new Geoprocessor("http://iicss63:6080/arcgis/rest/services/NCAOR/XYZtoR/GPServer");
```

You should try to enter the url in your browser to check if it's reachable.